# jQuery array to splited json

Tags: html, jquery

Hello I have am trying to build a post request. Below is the format that I have to send

```
const data = {
categories: [
    {
      id: 9
    },
    {
      id: 14
    }
  ],
}
```

But what I have is `["29", "23", "22"]` : these are category ids

Please help

Comment: You seem to have completely misunderstood how SO works then. It is not a help desk. You are expected to show some effort

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `.map`:

```js
const arr = ["29", "23", "22"];

const data = { 
  categories: arr.map( e => ({ id: e }) )
};

console.log(data);
```